# const qualification conversion

Tags: c++, constants, implicit-conversion, qualifiers

From (4.4/1 ) It reads

> An rvalue of type “pointer to cv1 T” can be converted to an rvalue of
>   type “pointer to cv2 T” if “cv2 T” is more cv-qualified than “cv1 T.”

I don't know where the standard defines 'more cv-qualifield' type but as I understood a declarator with const is more cv-qualified than than a non-const.

For following conversions, how does the quote from standard fits in or how you know which one is less or more cv-qualifed?

```
int *const c1 = 0;
int const* c2 = 0;
const int *const c3 = 0;

c1 = c2; // allowed
c1 = c3; // allowed
```

**Update:**

```
c2 = c1;
c2 = c3;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Table 6 in 3.9.3/4 gives the partial ordering of cv-qualifiers and 3.9.3/4 also gives the definition of *more cv-qualified*.

- *no cv-qualifier* < `const`
- *no cv-qualifier* < `volatile`
- *no cv-qualifier* < `const volatile`
- `const` < `const volatile`
- `volatile` < `const volatile`

Comment: Does that mean the conversions that I have in my example are unspecified by standard?

Comment: @cpx: It means that they aren't allowed because `int` is not `more cv-qualified` than `const int` and you are not simply addition `const` in ways allowed by 4.4./4. If the conversion was allowed you still couldn't assign to `c1` as `c1` is `const` (regardless of the cv-qualification of the pointed to type).

Comment: @cpx: Post-edit: the assignment `c2 = c3;` is legal as the types are the same (modulo top-level const) and the assignment `c2 = c1;` is legal as `const int` is more cv-qualified that `int`. I'm only reading the spec for you, though.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Thanks. though I knew the conversion is valid but it got me doubts when i opened the spec.

Answer (score 4):

Since `c1` is a `const` pointer variable (which is different to a pointer to constant data), it cannot be modified. Therefore, both assignments are illegal.

What the standard refers to is this case:

```
int *d1 = 0;
const int* d2 = d1; // d2 is more cv-qualified than d1
const volatile int* d3 = d1; // d3 is more cv-qualified than d2
```

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know where the standard defines 'more cv-qualifield' type

It is §3.9.3/4

> There is a (partial) ordering on cv-qualifiers, so that a type can be said to be **more cv-qualified** than another. Table 6 shows the relations that constitute this ordering.
>
> Table 6—relations on const and volatile
>
> ---
>
> ```
> no cv-qualifier  <  const  
> no cv-qualifier  <  volatile   
> no cv-qualifier  <  const volatile   
> const            <  const volatile   
> volatile         <  const volatile
> ```

That is,

- `const T` is *more cv-qualified* than `T`.
- `volatile T` is *more cv-qualified* than `T`.
- `const volatile T` is *more cv-qualified* than `T`.
- `const volatile T` is *more cv-qualified* than `const T`.
- `const volatile T` is *more cv-qualified* than `volatile T`.

Comment: Does that mean the conversions that I have in example are unspecified by standard? i.e out of `int *const to int const*` which is more cv-qualified or how do we get the idea that the conversion is going to be valid?

Comment: @cpx: `int * const` and `int const*` are incomparable in terms of *more cv-qualified*, because while `int * const` means the pointer is const (i.e `T` is `int*`), and `int const*` means the data is const (i.e `T` is `int`). The const-ness is applied on different objects in each; `T` is different in each case.